# Why string is expensive?

Tags: solidity, gas, evm, string

Sometimes we need to use `string` instead of `byte32` only because of one byte (or one character) and this increases the gas and the cost of transaction.

For example, I want to store the assets state of a building in blockchain. We have several  specific actions for these assets such that we have to mention exactly the title of an action ex. `Check operation of low water level float` that is `41 bytes`. So we cannot use `byte32` to store this action. And we need `string`.

According to [this article](https://media.consensys.net/technical-introduction-to-events-and-logs-in-ethereum-a074d65dd61e)

> Logs were designed to be a form of storage that costs significantly less gas than contract storage. Logs basically cost 8 gas per byte, whereas contract storage costs 20,000 gas per 32 bytes.

However,I am not sure in case of using `string` in `event`, **how much the cost will be decreased?**

What is the reason that `string` is more expensive than other types ? `Solidity` or `Ethereum` ? It depends on `consensus` mechanism used in the blockchain ? **And can it will resolved in future ?**

Here is some part of my `Solidity` code (I tried to summarize the code to be more clear. However, if you need more, please let me know.)

```
struct StateStruct {
                    mapping(bytes32 => bytes32) subState;
                }

                struct AssetStruct {
                    StateStruct state;
                    address owner; 
                    bool isAsset;
                    bytes32 review;
                    bytes32 action;
                    bytes32 player;
                    bytes32 actionState;
                    bytes32 assetSite;
                    bool isOwner;
                }

            mapping(uint256 => AssetStruct) assetStructs;
                uint256[] public assetList;

                uint256 public _public_id = 0;


       event LogNewAssetOneAction(uint256 indexed _id, bytes32 _action, bytes32 _player, bytes32 _actionState,  address _owner);

            function newAssetOneActionManualID(uint256 _id, bytes32 _action, bytes32 _player, bytes32 _actionState,  address _owner, bytes32 _assetSite) public returns(bool success) {
            require(!isAsset(_id));

            assetStructs[_id].owner = _owner;
            assetStructs[_id].isAsset = true;
            assetStructs[_id].assetSite = _assetSite;

            assetStructs[_id].action = _action;
            assetStructs[_id].player = _player;
            assetStructs[_id].actionState = _actionState;

            assetList.push(_id);

            emit LogNewAssetOneAction(uint256(_id), bytes32(_action), bytes32(_player), bytes32(_actionState), address(_owner));

            return true;
        }
```

Comment: Where is your code, and what is the gas difference you're seeing? `bytes32` can fit into a single 32-byte word, but anything longer will require storing a length and then multiple words. Perhaps this is the difference you're seeing.

Comment: @smarx Thank you. The source code is not currently available, however I add it to my question tomorrow. Thanks